# Error 1009 when importing PHP to Flash

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

been narrowing this problem down for a while and feel like I'm close to cracking it

I am getting the error Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://blahblahblah.com/questions.php");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

var loader2:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader2.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
loader2.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader2.load(request);

function completeHandler(event:Event) :void{
var questions:String = event.target.data.questions;
var questionsArray:Array=questions.split("/");
questionbox.question.text = questionsArray[numLoops];
trace("QuestionLoaded");
}
```

What's interesting is when I add a "." to the end of the URL so I have ".PHP." I get a different error code Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs

This is my PHP output

```
?questions=The+Sea+Swallow+is+an+alternative+name+for+which+bird%3F%2FIn+which+sport+would+you+see+a+Western+Roll%3F%2FWho+is+better+known+as%0B+Herbert+Khaury%3F%2FDiet+is+the+parliament+of+which+country%3F%2FWhat+is+the+real+first+name+of+Coco+Chanel%3F%2FThe+Aztecs+were+natives+of+which+country%3F%2FWhat+was+invented+by+O.A.+North+in+1869%3F%2FKing+Zog+was+the+ruler+of+which+country%3F&answers=Seagull%2FPenguin%2FTern%2FCormorant&correct=0%2F0%2F1%2F0
```

Thanks in advance for your help, really racking my brains over this. Suspecting an empty Variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the preceeding `?`, it will be parsed as a part of the key, which will cause the key to end up as `?questions`, consequently `questions` will be undefined, and trying to invoke `split` will throw the error.

The `?` is only used in URLs to separate the URL and the query string.

Comment: Try clearing your cache (on Windows the Standalone Flash Player uses Internet Explorers cache). Also check if you are receiving any data at all, and if so what exactly it looks like: `trace(event.target.data);`. If you are receving the correct data, then please specifiy where exactly the error is thrown!